# JQuery Datatable rows not deleting despite on calling clear function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

Im trying to remove all the rows in jquery data tables when new data arrives in order to fill with new rows.
But the problem is despite calling clear function it simply add the result rows to previous rows.
How to clear the rows in jquery data tables . Following is the code

```
var table = $("#editable");
                var tp = table.DataTable({
                    "paging": true,
                    "createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
                        $compile(row)($scope);
                    }
                });
//more code here ajax call only from angular post

                           if (result != null) {
                                $scope.reviews = result;
                                $window.toastr["success"]("Loaded Successfully !", "Recent Reviews");
                                tp.clear().draw();
                                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.reviews.length; i++) {
                                    var id = $scope.reviews[i].ID;
                                    var checked = $scope.reviews[i].Enabled == "1" ? true : false;
                                    tp.row.add([
                                        $scope.reviews[i].ID,
                                        $scope.reviews[i].AddedOn,
                                        $scope.reviews[i].Company.Name,
                                        $scope.reviews[i].Rate,
                                        $scope.reviews[i].User.Name,
                                        $scope.reviews[i].Description,
                                        "<div class='switch'><div class='onoffswitch'><input ng-model='$scope.reviews[" + i + "].Enabled' ng-click='ChangeReviewPublishStatus(" + $scope.reviews[i].ID + ")' ng-checked='" + checked + "' class='onoffswitch-checkbox' id= 'stat" + id + "' type= 'checkbox'><label class='onoffswitch-label' for='stat" + id + "'><span class='onoffswitch-inner'></span><span class='onoffswitch-switch'></span></label></div></div>"
                                    ]).draw();
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: i have tried using ng repeat , datatable doesnt work with ng repeat it dont create page when ng repeat is called

Comment: actually jquery data tables takes array and make into pages when ng repeat is used the data table paging function doenst run to make it to different pages rather it display the array to automatically into one page of long rows. i want to use data table paging functionality

Comment: Have you considered switching from DataTables to an Angular plugin like UI-Grid? It supports pagination and has some pretty advanced features. http://ui-grid.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would place that piece of code inside a `$timeout`. Both dataTables and angular wants to manipulate the DOM - angular wins the battle and by that dataTables never get a chance to finish its business. A `$timeout` will force the dataTables `clear()` and data population into the next digest, and ensure it is actually executed.

```
$timeout(function() {
    tp.clear().draw();
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.reviews.length; i++) {
        var id = $scope.reviews[i].ID;
        var checked = $scope.reviews[i].Enabled == "1" ? true : false;
        tp.row.add([
            $scope.reviews[i].ID,
            $scope.reviews[i].AddedOn,
            //etc
        ]).draw();
    }
});
```

Well, that is at least my theory - cannot replicate your scenario in full - let me know if it makes any difference.